# Multimonitor display settings reset after one display is turned off

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

**Setup:**
I have two monitors connected to my GPU, one using DisplayPort, and one using a HDMI to DVI cable. The DisplayPort one is my main monitor.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 with Nvidia driver 418 on a GTX1070 with XFCE.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

$ uname -a
Linux abulafia 5.0.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 12:04:58 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ nvidia-settings -v
nvidia-settings:  version 418.56
```

**Problem description:**
Turning off my main (DisplayPort) monitor with the physical button on it, will cause Ubuntu to use my secondary display as the only display. But turning my main display back on won't reconfigure my layout correctly. Specifically, it will select to mirror the display and overlay them. This results in me having to reconfigure it manually. It can't detect when I physically turn my secondary display off, and will still output to it when it is turned off, so the problem doesn't happen in reverse.

[image: Before turning off primary display]

[image: After turning primary display back on]

**What I tried:**
Checking the *Configure new display when connected* box in the display settings, which results in asking me about how to configure the displays when turning the main one back on. This kind of restores my settings, but I still have to reconfigure it because it creates a "gap" between the monitors:

[image: Showing gap in display settings]

I also tried configuring the displays in `nvidia-settings`, which didn't change anything. I can't try saving my settings to `xorg.conf` because I hit this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/1822937).

**Expected results:**
I want my display/window setup to stay the same, even when turning off the display and not being asked which setup I want. Basically Ubuntu should ignore me physically turning off the display and continue to output to it.

I use the same display setup with a Debian PC with Intel integrated graphics (main monitor connected through HDMI), where my layout stays the same when turning off the monitors, so I know it is possible.

Comment: hint and bandaid solution : this sets one monitor in relation to the other and makes one primary. xrandr on its own gets the display names
xrandr --output eDP  --auto --output HDMI-A-0 --primary --left-of eDP 
save as script then set a shorcut key for it.